# C# mongodb ObjectId useage risks

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I was watching on Mongodb ObjectId object.
It seems to be non-safe object to expose to my client (even its his own SessionId).
Though im using the following code to generate random ObjectIds:

```
var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var machine = _random.Next(10000, 75757575);
        var pid = (short)_random.Next(10000, 75757575);
        var increment = _random.Next(10000, 75757575);

        return new ObjectId(timestamp, machine, pid, increment);
```

I get sequential ids sometimes and I dont want the user to be able to guess 1 million ids and finally catches a real one.

Is there any way to still use mongodb on c# and maintain a secure id?
Now, some say "use https", but that's not the issue.
Someone can log into the web, get a sessionId of type ObjectId and try to guess.

How can I reduce the likelyhood of something like that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any sensitive information stored in the DB, you should apply some ACL rules in your application to decide whether user can retrieve data by objectId or not.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of an ACL rule if im using the ObjectId as a user token for requests from client to server?

Comment: Oh, I see. So you are using ObjectId to **identify** user. Don't do that. Issue a **random session token** on login for this purposes.

Comment: Yeah of course. I AM using this. The session is alive for a month of inactivity basically.. If user is returning after a month it is replaced.maybe ill change it to be replaced every month regardless.. without extensions. But still, is it enough?  The code i attached is what creating the random sessions id. Is the ObjectId playing a safe roll here?

Comment: No, ObjectId does not add any security. Why not to use standard crypto library? Something like  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx. Especially considering extremely long ttl.

Comment: Ill do that. Thought of it too, just wondered if string processing within each request is right and not wasteful